# Content of directory on path https://xxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxx-org5a2/account/Snapshot/2018-08_1656570292/*.csv' cannot be listed

Tags: azure-synapse

When I try to query our Serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics I get the following error:

```
"Content of directory on path 'https://xxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxxxx-org5a2bcccf/account/Snapshot/2018-08_1656570292/*.csv' cannot be listed.".
```

I have checked out the following link for clues as to what could be cause:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002

It is suggested that the error is due permissions:

However, I believe I have the correct permissons,

[image]

I get this error whether I try to execute the query in SSMS or Synapse Workspace.

The error in SSMS is as follows:

```
Warning: Unable to resolve path https://xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxxx-org5a2bcccf/account/Snapshot/2018-10_1657304551/*.csv. Error number 13807, Level 16, State 1, Message "Content of directory on path 'https://xxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxxx-org5a2bcccf/account/Snapshot/2018-10_1657304551/*.csv' cannot be listed.".
```

[image]

Can someone let me know how to resolve this?
The query that I'm attempting to execute can be located here:
https://github.com/slavatrofimov/Synapse-Link-for-Dataverse-data-enrichment-in-Serverless-SQL-Pools/blob/main/SQL/Enrich%20Synapse%20Link%20for%20Dataverse%20Entities%20with%20Human-Readable%20Labels.sql

Is there a definitive way to determine if the problem is due to lack of permissions?

Update Question:
I have just realised that the issue is access the Lake on https://xxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxxxx-org5a2bcccf/

Therefore please take a look at my permissons on the lake and let me know if it is sufficient?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when the user trying to query the external table does not have the relevant permissions or if there is a firewall enabled on your storage network.

When looked at the permissions you have provided, I see `Storage Blob Data reader` and `Storage Blob Data contributor` have been given.

Ref doc: [Control storage account access for serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity#storage-permissions)

[image]

In case if your storage account is firewall protect then you will have to follow the steps described in this document to overcome the issue: [Access storage that is protected with the firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity#firewall-protected-storage)

Here are couple of relevant articles which might help you configure your storage firewall to overcome this issue:

1. [Storage configuration for external table is not accessible while query on Serverless](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/storage-configuration-for-external-table-is-not-accessible-while/ba-p/2020523)
2. [Synapse Studio error while trying to read data from Storage Account using SQL On Demand](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/synapse-studio-error-while-trying-to-read-data-from-storage/ba-p/1511965)

Answer (score 0):

The solution may not be complex. Check the column data type using below:

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 
    TOP 10 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''data source url'',
        FORMAT = ''DELTA''
    ) AS [result]'
```

If your data type is not proper and big digressively like varchar(8000), you encounter this error. Just write necessary columns and partition columns of file(e.g. year, month).

```
SELECT TOP 100
       *
   FROM OPENROWSET(
       BULK 'data source url',
       FORMAT = 'DELTA'
   ) 
   WITH (
        column1 datatype1,
        column2 datatype2,
        ...
        year VARCHAR(4),   --if year is a partition column of file, it is required.
        month VARCHAR(2)   --if month is a partition column of file, it is required.
   )AS [result];
```